# Redux connect() with multiples actions / states

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-framework

What is the proper way of connecting multiple states with corresponding action creators in Redux?

Is that even a good idea?
How can I work around that if it's a stupid idea?

```
export default connect(

// which part of the Redux global state does
// our component want to receive as props?
(state) => {
  return {
    state: state.instagram
  };
},

// which action creators does
// it want to receive by props?
(dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(instagramActions, dispatch)
  };
}

)(FeedContainer);
```

What I basically want is something like this:

```
...
state: {state.instagram, state.facebook}
...

...
const mergedActions = {instagramActions, facebookActions};
actions: bindActionCreators(mergedActions , dispatch)
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the provided callbacks mapStateTopProps and mapDispatchToProps is the proper way to connect your component with a filtered subset of your state and already bound actionCreators.

To achieve what you want you could simply do:

```
(state) => {
  const { instagram, facebook } = state;
  return {
    state: { instagram, facebook }
  };
}
```

and

```
(dispatch) => {
  return {
     actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, instagramActions, facebookActions), dispatch)
  };
}
```

This does not work:

```
actions: bindActionCreators({instagramActions, facebookActions} , dispatch)
```

as the method does not support nested objects yet. [See code here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/bindActionCreators.js).
It only iterates over the keys and looks for functions.

Within your mapDispatchToProps callback you could leave the extra state layer away

```
(state) => {
   const { instagram, facebook } = state;
   return {
      instagram, 
      facebook
   };
}
```

By doing this you can access the props with:

`this.props.facebook` and `this.props.instagram` instead of 
`this.props.state.facebook` and `this.props.state.instagram`. But this is only a question of style I think.

There are several ways of binding your state and dispatch to props. In the end it is a question of style. I could provide several different examples of how to do it, but better take a look into the official documentation and find your own style https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Even if you don't require multiple action creators in your component props, it's wise to stick to one convention across all your components.

Comment: how do you call `facebookActions` from the component then? I used to call `this.props.facebookActions` but now I get error: `_this2.props.facebookActions` is not a function...

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simple do that:

```js
import * as todoActionCreators from './todoActionCreators'
import * as counterActionCreators from './counterActionCreators'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    todoActions: bindActionCreators(todoActionCreators, dispatch),
    counterActions: bindActionCreators(counterActionCreators, dispatch)
  }
}
```

as shown in react-redux documentation

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone else wants to map all actions into a single key in `this.props` (like me), I am adding my two cents here.

Expanding on DavinTryon's comment on the accepted answer, another way to achieve "`mergedActions`" is by using the spread operator, especially if you want to use one key (say, `actions`) for all actions and call them using `this.props.actions.[specificAction]`. Here is what you have to do in the `connect` method:

```
export default connect(
(state) => {
  return {
    state: state.instagram
  };
},

(dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({...instagramActions, facebookActions}, dispatch)
  };
}

)(FeedContainer);
```

In case you are declaring the methods separately (with something like `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps`), you can write your `mapDispatchToProps` as follows:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...instagramActions, facebookActions }, dispatch)
  };
};
```

This will map all your action creators in both `facebookActions` and `instagramActions` to `this.props.actions`.